# Applying global styling through a component

Tags: html, css, angular, web-component

I'm creating a library for Angular which I'll then publish to NPM.

After the user imports the library into their Angular app, they'll be able to use the the component like

```
 <lib-ngx-feature
  [settings]=myStetings
 ></lib-ngx-feature>
```

In that component there's a `(click)` event which should trigger changes to the styling of the whole DOM, not only the `lib-ngx-feature`. How can I target the styling of the whole app through that component ? using something like `:host` didn't work and I'm not sure I can approach this through `app.service.ts` for example since this package will be installed through NPM.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If it's like that `<lib-ngx-feature [settings]="mySettings" (click)="myClickHandler($event)"></lib-ngx-feature>` then in the calling component you can update a `Subject` saved in e.g. `app.service.ts`, and subscribe to this subject anywhere you wish and impact component class like `[class.special]="value"`

Comment: @Benny How can I save the `Subject` in `app.service.ts` if this is going to be a package that a user installs through NPM ? do I add that step in the installation docs that they should initialize a `Subject` in that file ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your library inner working or its purpose. I assumed that the component exposes a click handler. The idea of a `Subject` is just an example of how the library consumer can handle the click and do what he likes with it, including changing style. Admittedly my assumption may be wrong - so best would be that you provide code that demonstrates how this library/component is actually used.

Comment: The html of the component has three buttons, when one of them is clicked it should change the font color of the whole app. so it doesn't really have a click event as you described above, but three click events *inside* the component html.
so what I was wondering is how to apply that style change to the whole app through that component.

Comment: Then perhaps what you need is to access the body element and style it directly. As in `document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'red';`. Note that the consumer may have css code that can override the styling your library sets.

Comment: @Benny would a `ViewEncapsulation.None` serve that purpose ? for the styling in that component to apply the whole app.

Comment: It may do. It's simple to try. Did you?